# Replace cycle in R

Tags: r

I have an example of code witch finds in vector `z` values less then `-1.8` and fills in `1` while the values of `z` don't become larger than `0` else filling in `0`.

I use two cycles, but it is very slow.

How can I make this simpler and more efficient?

```
z <- c(-1,-1.4,-1.1,-1.8,-2.2,-2.5,-1.7,-1,-0.5,-0.1,0.2,0.4)

q <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(z)) {
  if (z[i] <= -1.8) {
    temp <- 1
  }else temp <- 0
  q <- rbind(q, temp)
}

for (i in 2:length(q)) {
  if (z[i] < 0 & q[i-1] == 1) {
    q[i] <- 1
  }
}

q
     [,1]
temp    0
temp    0
temp    0
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    0
temp    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid loops and do this in one line if you do:

```r
cumsum(c(0, diff(+(z <= -1.8)) == 1) - c(0, diff(+(z > 0) == 1)))
#> [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

This works by finding where `z` is less than or equal to -1.8, and converting the resulting logical vector to a 1 or 0. It then finds where this changes from a 0 to a 1 using `diff`. Similarly, it finds where the values cross above 0 and marks that with a -1. Finally it gets the cumulative sum of this vector.

If you need a more complete solution, one tidyverse option would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

z <- c(-1, -1.4, -1.1, -1.8, -2.2, -2.5, -1.7, -1, -0.5, -0.1,
       0.2, 0.4, -0.5, -1.2, -2, -0.6, -0.1, 0.5) 
 
tibble(z) %>%
  mutate(z = (z <= -1.8) - (z > 0),
         z = (1 + replace(z, z == 0, NA))/2) %>%
  fill(z) %>%
  replace_na(list(z = 0))
#> # A tibble: 18 x 1
#>        z
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     0
#>  2     0
#>  3     0
#>  4     1
#>  5     1
#>  6     1
#>  7     1
#>  8     1
#>  9     1
#> 10     1
#> 11     0
#> 12     0
#> 13     0
#> 14     0
#> 15     1
#> 16     1
#> 17     1
#> 18     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: is worth noting that after I have filled in 1, I must wait again until the values are less than -1.8 and start filling in 1 again only from the moment when z becomes equal to -1.8

more advanced example:

z <- c(-1,-1.4,-1.1,-1.8,-2.2,-2.5,-1.7,-1,-0.5,-0.1,0.2,0.4,-0.5,-1.2,-2,-0.6,-0.1,0.5)

what should happend:  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0

Comment: @МихаилТабаков see my update. Hopefully this will be quicker